# What does the term 'Utility' refer to for a class in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was reading a guide online and one of the pro's for a class said that it has "excellent utility".

What does 'utility' refer to in this case? What kind of traits would a class with 'excellent utility' have?

**Overall, what does the term 'Utility' refer to in World of Warcraft?**

Comment: Anything other than tanking, damage or healing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utility refers to non-combat abilities, such as a mage being able to create portals and food, a warlock being able to summon raid members, and many classes being able to crowd control and provide raidwide buffs.

Comment: Actually, buff spells were gone in Legion and only just recently returned.  Not all of them though as Mark of the Wild for Druids is still MIA.

Comment: Right, so they're included here. I'm also referring to heroism/bloodlust